# Ignore default text in jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using the jquery validation plugin (bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/id) for a bit of client-side form validation. The plugin is working great but I cannot figure out how to force it to ignore some default text within a textarea.

```
<form action="#" id="landingForm">
<p>
<textarea id="askTexarea" class="required textarea" name="askTextarea" cols="7" rows="3">THIS IS THE DEFAULT TEXT</textarea>
</p>
<p>
<label for="askExpert">Pick an Expert:</label>
<select id="askExpert" class="required select" name="askExpert">
    <option></option>
    <option>CHOICE 1</option>
    <option>CHOICE 2</option>
    <option>CHOICE 3</option>
</select>
</p>
<p class="email">
<label for="askEmail">Enter your email address:</label>
<input id="askEmail" class="required email" name="email" />
</p>
<p class="submit">
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Ask a Question" />
</p>
</form>
```

You will notice in the first textarea  there is default text. Does anyone know how to make the validation plugin ignore this text and consider it invalid if a user submits the form with this default text or if the textarea is empty?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [custom method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod) that checks for the default text:

```
$.validator.addMethod("defaulText", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || element[0].defaultText != value;
}, "Please replace the default text");
```

Didn't yet test this implementation - if element[0].defaultText doesn't give the right value, replace that with an inline string.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this alongside the plugin code:

```
if ($('#askTextarea')[0].value=="THIS IS THE DEFAULT TEXT") // invalidate code here
```

Comment: I keep trying this out but it seems to give a syntax error. Any other suggestions? Thanks for you help!

Comment: This is the js I have so far. Please let me know if you see any issues and where exactly I should put the line you suggested. Thanks again for all your help!

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#landingForm').validate({
        rules: {
            askEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
            },
            askTextarea: {
                required: true,
            },
            askExpert: {
                required: true
            },
        },
    });

});

Comment: You know, you might as well just put this right before validation so the default text is invalidated:
if ($('#askTextarea')[0].value=="THIS IS THE DEFAULT TEXT") $('#askTextarea')[0].value="";

Answer (score 0):

As from what I read in your question, what you were trying to do with the "DEFAULT TEXT" was to display a *placeholder* - a prompt to the user to enter text, but not a value to be sent to the server.

In that case you are better served with an HTML5 placeholder attribute.