# function to validate text box on blank or default text

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

```
function checkForm(f) {
    if (f.elements['zoom_query'].value == "" || "Search - Movie or Actor") {
        f.zoom_query.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        f.submit();
        return false;
    }
}
```

this prevents form submission for any string

any idea?

Comment: what is your question? you gotta improve that. your asking or you're saying that "this prevents form submission for any string" ?

Comment: I am trying to validate a text box so that if the default value for the text box or a blank value is provided, it prevents the form from being submitted. sorry for being vague

Comment: come up with html example, its unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should read:

`(f.elements['zoom_query'].value == "" || f.elements['zoom_query'].value == "Search - Movie or Actor")`

Otherwise it always evaluates true

Comment: if you like the answer then give me a green tick and a vote - that's how this site works, I see you are new here, welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery I'd recommend having a look here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392718/ignore-default-text-in-jquery-validation-plugin) contains an answer that solves the problem you're having using jQuery Form Validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkForm(f) {

    if (f.zoom_query.value == "" || f.zoom_query.value == "Search - Movie or Actor") {
        alert("Please fill in the text field.");
        f.zoom_query.focus();
        return (false);
    }

    f.submit();
    return (true);
}
```